# Transpose Mysql queries for Magento

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am looking to transpose the result of the following query which gives the below mentioned result.

```
SELECT pro_dec.entity_id,
       attr.attribute_id,
       attr.attribute_code AS attribute_name,
       pro_dec.VALUE
FROM   `magento_eav_attribute` AS attr
       INNER JOIN magento_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pro_dec
         ON pro_dec.attribute_id = attr.attribute_id
WHERE  attr.`entity_type_id` = 4
       AND attr.`backend_type` = 'decimal'
ORDER  BY pro_dec.entity_id 


//Output1
entity_id   attribute_id    attribute_name  value
   376      60              price   25.0000
   376      65              weight  1.0000
   377      60              price   35.0000
   377      65              weight  3.0000
```

I am trying to achieve the following output result

```
//Output2
entity_id   price    weight
   376      25.0000   1.0000
   377      35.0000   3.0000
```

I have written a rather long nested select query which gives me the desired result. Is there any better/simpler way to get the query for Output2 given that I have the query for Output 1.

//Edit 1
Here is the nested query I had written. This is only for two attributes price and weight.

```
SELECT ent.entity_id,
       ent.type_id,
       (SELECT pro_dec.VALUE AS VALUE
        FROM   `magento_eav_attribute` AS attr
               INNER JOIN magento_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pro_dec
                 ON pro_dec.attribute_id = attr.attribute_id
        WHERE  attr.`entity_type_id` = 4
               AND attr.`backend_type` = 'decimal'
               AND attr.attribute_id = 60
               AND pro_dec.entity_id = ent.entity_id
        ORDER  BY pro_dec.entity_id) AS price,
       (SELECT pro_dec.VALUE AS VALUE
        FROM   `magento_eav_attribute` AS attr
               INNER JOIN magento_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pro_dec
                 ON pro_dec.attribute_id = attr.attribute_id
        WHERE  attr.`entity_type_id` = 4
               AND attr.`backend_type` = 'decimal'
               AND attr.attribute_id = 65
               AND pro_dec.entity_id = ent.entity_id
        ORDER  BY pro_dec.entity_id) AS weight
FROM   magento_catalog_product_entity AS ent
```

//Edit 2
Here's the Join query which again is a bit bloated and perhaps can be optimized

```
SELECT ent.entity_id,
       ent.type_id,
       price.VALUE  AS price,
       weight.VALUE AS weight
FROM   magento_catalog_product_entity AS ent
       INNER JOIN (SELECT pro_dec.entity_id   AS entity_id,
                          attr.attribute_id   AS attribute_id,
                          attr.attribute_code AS attribute_name,
                          pro_dec.VALUE       AS VALUE
                   FROM   `magento_eav_attribute` AS attr
                          INNER JOIN magento_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS
                                     pro_dec
                            ON pro_dec.attribute_id = attr.attribute_id
                   WHERE  attr.`entity_type_id` = 4
                          AND attr.`backend_type` = 'decimal'
                          AND attr.attribute_id = 60
                   ORDER  BY pro_dec.entity_id) AS price
         ON price.entity_id = ent.entity_id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT pro_dec.entity_id   AS entity_id,
                          attr.attribute_id   AS attribute_id,
                          attr.attribute_code AS attribute_name,
                          pro_dec.VALUE       AS VALUE
                   FROM   `magento_eav_attribute` AS attr
                          INNER JOIN magento_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS
                                     pro_dec
                            ON pro_dec.attribute_id = attr.attribute_id
                   WHERE  attr.`entity_type_id` = 4
                          AND attr.`backend_type` = 'decimal'
                          AND attr.attribute_id = 65
                   ORDER  BY pro_dec.entity_id) AS weight
         ON weight.entity_id = ent.entity_id
WHERE  ent.type_id = 'configurable'
```

Comment: Please post your nested query, to check if it can be optimized. Basically, to write own nested queries for reports is the way to go. If you using your data in your application (i.e. business logic) you should stick using the Magento ORM (Zend DB) and sort the results afterwards.

Comment: added my query to the question ..

Comment: Initially I tried to use the Magento Core Api with ruby but the api calls were too slow. I also had trouble with the savon and magentor gems for making xmlrpc/soap calls . So i thought of getting down to the query level.

Comment: Your query looks good so far. The Magento API isn't really fast, that's right. An alternative would be to use JOINs instead ob Subselects. But such a query would also be very complex and I don't know if it will be (much) faster.

Comment: I have added the Join query .. Is this optimizable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for [Pivot Table](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table). 
Using SUM/GROUP_CONCAT along with IF , can transpose a table

Answer (score 1):

Something like that. It may certainly need adjustments. EAV leads to complicated-looking queries:

```
SELECT 
       ent.entity_id,
       ent.type_id, 
       pro_dec1.value   AS price,
       pro_dec2.value   AS weight
FROM   
       magento_catalog_product_entity AS ent 

     INNER JOIN 
       magento_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pro_dec1
         ON  pro_dec1.entity_id = ent.entity_id
     INNER JOIN
       magento_eav_attribute AS at1
         ON  at1.attribute_id = pro_dec1.attribute_id
         AND at1.entity_type_id = 4
         AND at1.backend_type = 'decimal'
         AND at1.attribute_code = 'price'

     INNER JOIN 
       magento_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pro_dec2
         ON  pro_dec2.entity_id = ent.entity_id
     INNER JOIN 
       magento_eav_attribute AS at2
         ON  at2.attribute_id = pro_dec2.attribute_id
         AND at2.entity_type_id = 4
         AND at2.backend_type = 'decimal'
         AND at2.attribute_code = 'value'

WHERE  
       ent.type_id = 'configurable' 

ORDER BY 
       ent.entity_id
```